# Fatal Error: Duplicate keys of type 'Geocoded Placemark' were found in a dictionary. (Mapbox Geocoder)

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, mapbox, geocoding

I quote: "This usually means either that the type violates Hashable's requirements, or that members of such a dictionary were mutated after insertion."

I'm using the Mapbox Geocoder , and when this runtime error occured, my XCode brought me to Thread 1, 0_swift_runtime_on_report and the error occured on the commented line below:

```
libswiftCore.dylib`_swift_runtime_on_report:
    0x10fdd2180 <+0>: pushq %rbp //this line right here
```

I've never seen this error before and I don't even begin to know how to approach it. I'm sorry I'm not putting any of my project code into it, but I don't even know how to interpret this error to figure out which code I should be fixing. How do I even know what dictionary it's referring to? If I can add anything to this, please let me know.

Comment: In the menu on left hand side there should be a "Debug Navigator" tab that will show you a minimal stack trace that you can navigate through. That should help a bit.

Comment: If I'm seeing the same thing, this fatalError looks like it's stack trace is all swiftUI library code. It must be something to do with the way swiftUI is looking up state / binding variables. @nickcoding were you passing a binding down through multiple views?

Comment: @ethoooo So I fixed it--I think the source of the error was the geocoded results not being displayed as fast as the user was typing. That made it so that before the view had refreshed, the binding had already changed so I fixed it be implementing a custom textfield instead of the built in ones.