# " Duplicate keys of type ... were found in a Dictionary " when there is no Dictionary?

Tags: swift, foundation

I'm quite new to Swift and I just encountered an error I don't find a solution for. I'm currently working on a game (Boggle, for the curious) and I want to update the list of words that the algorithm has found.

I created a struct to hold each word and the points it scores :

```
struct ScoredWord: Comparable, Identifiable{
let word: String
var points: Int = 0
let id: UUID

init(word: String){
    self.id = UUID()
    self.word = word
    self.points = self.defineScore(word: word)
}

static func < (lhs: ScoredWord, rhs: ScoredWord) -> Bool {}

static func == (lhs: ScoredWord, rhs: ScoredWord) -> Bool {}

func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {

private func defineScore(word: String) -> Int{}
```

(I removed the content of the func for it's useless to you)

Once the algorithm is done, I have simple loop that created a struct for each word found and stores it in the array that is @Published for display

```
let foundWords = solver.findValidWords()
    
for found in foundWords {
    wordList.append(ScoredWord(word: found))
}
```

The array is used in my view this way:

```
 List(wordListViewModel.wordList, id: \.self) { // 1 Word list
     Text( $0.word )
     Spacer()
     Text("\( $0.points )")
 }
```

The error I get when I run all of this is:

```
Fatal error: Duplicate keys of type 'ScoredWord' were found in a Dictionary. 
This usually means either that the type violates Hashable's requirements, or
that members of such a dictionary were mutated after insertion.
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62032654/fatal-error-duplicate-keys-of-type-geocoded-placemark-were-found-in-a-diction) about the same error where a comment states that the error would come from the list not being displayed fast enough and id getting mixed up, but nothing about how to fix it...

Any idea?

Comment: Show the code in `hash(into:)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are missing a full conformance to the [Hashable Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable)

Pay attention to the `func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher)` function which you are missing

Comment: Hi @CloudBalancing, thanks for the reply, I indeed missed this func in my struct. Adding it didn't fix my issue though :(

Comment: Please share the implementation of the function, it probably means that your implementation produce the same Hasher for two different struct instances

Comment: Here is what I did:
```func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
        hasher.combine(word)
        hasher.combine(points)
    }```

Comment: Did you update your `==` function, i.e equatable function to take the UUID into account as well?

Comment: Ok, I'm really ashamed of myself. I should have added the funcs content after all, you would have spotted this mistake earlier... Thanks a lot @CloudBalancing, it fixed my issue !

Comment: Cool ,happy it helped. BTW - if you. are using UUID - you can remove the dependancy on the word and points variables, as their value will not affect the results (that is the idea of using UUID - which suppose to be unique per initialisation...)

Answer (score 0):

Hash table is a dictionary. [What is the true difference between a dictionary and a hash table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061222/what-is-the-true-difference-between-a-dictionary-and-a-hash-table)

It appears that some structs in your array are made using identical words & points. Add another variable to your struct:

var identifier = UUID()

It will generate a unique ID.

Comment: Thanks for the post! I had the same thoughts and tried to add an ID to each struct in the past, but it ended up the same way... I just tried again with the UUID, but I still get my error

Comment: If it’s not this, then you should look into the error message’s second part that mentions wrong conformance to the protocol or mutation of properties

Comment: Just for the hell of it, change those vars to lets

Comment: Yes, that's what CloudBalancing is suggesting in his answer

Comment: @ano0ther Just make sure that the same struct is not being used multiple times.

Comment: That wasn't the case, but I forgot to update the == func with the UUID, so there was a bad matching happening. Thanks for the help!